# How to install FLOSS (FLARE Obfuscated String Solver) from github in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, command, github-pages

Could someone please help me to install FLOSS (FLARE Obfuscated String Solver) in ubuntu?

Instructions are provided in the following github page but I still don't know how to install it.

What is the exact command line that I need to use in ubuntu to install floss?

https://github.com/mandiant/flare-floss
https://github.com/mandiant/flare-floss/releases

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps:

https://github.com/mandiant/flare-floss/blob/master/doc/installation.md

how you want to run? standalone or with python?

For standalone, just download below:
https://github.com/mandiant/flare-floss/releases

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the answer. Remember to copy the vital parts of the answer out into your answer here. And still keep the link to where you found it. That way, 30 years from now, when the other user has deleted his Github-account, your answer is still current. :-)